# Why For loop stop when When the case is except?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop

for loop stop In case of except When using the line :
page.close()

```
from selenium import webdriver
page = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
page.maximize_window()
def test():
    for i in range(10):
        page.execute_script("window.open()")
        page.switch_to.window(page.window_handles[i + 1])
        page.get(f"https://haraj.com.sa/119174396{i}")
        try:
            Object = page.find_element_by_class_name("contact")
            Object.click()
        except:
            page.close()
            print("Not find element ")
test()
```

If the find element ("contact") click on it, And the page stays open in Browser Tab
If the element ("contact") is not find, the page will be closed And for loop continues
If commented  #page.close() the for loop will continue And the page that I want to close will stays open in Browser Tab and print("Not find element ") function will be executed
Are there other ways to close the page that does not contain element ("contact") and continue for loop?

Comment: Please format the code as code block (use the `{}` button) and make sure the indentation is right.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem in your code is you are closing browser and then you want to locate element so it will generate error.

There are two solution below

Solution 1:

```
from selenium import webdriver
page = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
page.maximize_window()
def test():
    for i in range(10):
        page.execute_script("window.open()")
        page.switch_to.window(page.window_handles[i + 1])
        page.get(f"https://haraj.com.sa/119174396{i}")
        try:
            Object = page.find_element_by_class_name("contact")
            Object.click()
        except:
            page.close()
            print("Not find element ")
            page = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
            page.maximize_window()
test()
```

When element('contact') is not find Above code close the browser and reopen browser again and continue execution

Solution 2:

```
from selenium import webdriver
page = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
page.maximize_window()
def test():
    for i in range(10):
        page.execute_script("window.open()")
        page.switch_to.window(page.window_handles[i + 1])
        page.get(f"https://haraj.com.sa/119174396{i}")
        try:
            Object = page.find_element_by_class_name("contact")
            Object.click()
        except:
            print("Not find element ")
test()
```

Above code will not close browser so it will remain same as before exception and continue execution

Comment: Solution 1: Pages won't open
Solution 2: Continues without closing pages where element ("contact") does Not Found

Comment: If my answer helps you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer and also upvote